# storing all function body from txt file in dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to do code analyzer app and i have a txt file that contains a python code and my goal now is to save all functions in this txt file in dictionary in the class, but i don't have any idea how can i do it

at first i create class that name is `class CodeAnalyzer:`

```
def __init__(self, file):
    self.file = file
    self.file_string = ""
    self.file_func= {}
    self.errors = {}
```

and i want to save function in **self.file_func= {}**

this is process step, every method should return key and value added to attributes

```
def process_file(self):
        for i, line in enumerate(self.file):
            self.file_string += line
            self.check_divide_by_zero(i, line)
            self.check_parameters_num(i, line)
```

This what i tried to do but ie's failed :

```
def store_function(self,i,line):
            if(line.startswith('def')):
                self.file_func.setdefault(i,[]).append((self.file_string[file_string.index(':') ,:]))
```

Any one have an Idea or help on it ?

Comment: Are you manually parsing the source code? If so, any reason why you aren't using `ast`?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark what is ast and how can it helps ?

Comment: It's a builtin module for parsing [abstract syntax trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), which give a tree-based representaiton of the source code.

Comment: What are the contents of your text file, and your desired output? There's quite a few ways to achieve this by simply using `eval`, which are much easier than using `ast`.

Comment: @Mous it's contains text that represent python code should be analyzes

Comment: Does it only contain function definitions, or does it contain variables too? If you could post the text file attached to the question, or if it's too big attach a pastebin link.

Comment: @Mous there is no specific text file, it's should be any python code (any assumptions of a file content) with all functionalities variales,classes, functions .. etc and it should to be analysis

Comment: I'll post a code snippet with explanation, I just need to check the best way to perform this.

Comment: Do you want variables to become attributes of the class, or just functions, specifically?

Comment: @Mous it's should be better (Y)

Comment: The solution is simple then. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Do you want the functions and attributes to be stored as attributes of the class instance itself, or in an attribute of the class instance (presumably a dictionary)?

Comment: @Mous in a dictionary will be better i think, it's made code more flexible, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `exec()` with it's globals() dict set to your class instance's namespace.

```py
class CodeAnalyzer:
  def __init__(self,file):
    # Read a string from the file
    f=open(file)
    t=f.read()
    f.close()

    #Populate the namespace dictionary by executing the code in the file
    self.namespace={}#this includes all declarations of functions, variables and classes
    exec(t,self.namespace)#this means that when variables are declared, they use the class instance's attributes dictionary as their global namespace

    #Filter the namespace dict based on the contents
    self.functions={i:self.namespace[i] for i in self.namespace if isinstance(i,type(lambda:0))}#type(lambda:0) is just FunctionType
    self.classes={i:self.namespace[i] for i in self.namespace if isinstance(i,type)}#all classes are instances of type
    self.variables={i:self.namespace[i] for i in self.namespace if i not in self.functions|self.classes}#everything else, using dictionary merge
```

Feel free to comment on this answer if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! , but i have small problem , that functions may written using Normal defined function, not just as lambda, how can i solve it ?

Comment: Normal defined functions will also be detected, as they are also instances of FunctionType.

Comment: In fact, function declarations and lambda functions assigned to a variable can only be told apart via their names, because they are both instances of FunctionType.

Comment: This is not going to catch lambdas (separately, anyway).  lambdas do not exist in a namespace, unless you assign them to a variable name.  Also remember this is going to execute the script as well as parse it.  That might be OK for what you're doing, unless it triggers a missile launch.

Comment: You could extract lambdas via direct CodeObject manipulation, but that's probably overkill. Also, it's literally impossible to determine if a function will be declared in an arbitrary without running it - doing so is equivalent to the halting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the isinstance check should be

```
self.functions={i:self.namespace[i] for i in self.namespace if isinstance(self.namespace[i],type(lambda:0))}
```

we want to test the i-th element of the self.namespace, not the value of i.